# How to connect remote Spark cluster from Local Windows Rstudio

Tags: apache-spark, rstudio, apache-spark-sql, sparkr, rstudio-server

I have Spark cluster in my **remote centos nodes** and i want to connect that **remote Spark cluster from my local windows R studio**  (I am using **Rstudio Desktop** in my local windows)

```
  if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
  Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/home/remoteclusterpath/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6")
  .libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
}
library(SparkR, lib.loc = "/home/remoteclusterpath/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/R/lib")

sc <- sparkR.init(master = "spark://<IP-Address>:7077", sparkEnvir = list(spark.driver.memory="2g"))
```

I am getting this below error

```
Error in library(SparkR) : there is no package called ‘SparkR’
```

please anyone provide me the solution thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To use SparkR in RStudio you need install SparkR package and load it. Use these commands

```
install.packages("SparkR")

library(SparkR)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use SparkR in RStudio you may install sparklyr putting this command on RStudio console:

```
intall.packages("sparklyr")
```

Later, you can load this package with this command:

```
library("sparklyr")
```